# How to upload a video to Facebook event page via PHP

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-events, video-upload

I have created an event on my test page and I'm going to upload a video to that event page from my web site. I have used the below code but it is doesn't work.

```
$data = [
       'title' => 'test Video',
       'description' => 'This is test video',
       'source' => $fb->videoToUpload($video_path),
];

try {
       $response = $fb->post('/' . $event_id . '/videos', $data, $page_token);
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
       return 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e){
       return 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

$graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
```

I got this error.

> Graph returned an error:(#33) This object does not exist or does not support this action.

So I fix some parts like this.

```
$data = [    
   .......
   'source' => $video_path
];
try{
   $response = $fb->post('/' . $event_id . '/feed', $data, $page_token);
}
.......
```

[Then it works like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C11ZC.png)

[But I want to result like as this picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUznD.png)

How shall I do?

Comment: Have you tried to see all official reference: [Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_upload_video/) 
Are you sure $video_path contain path like reference?

Comment: Thanks. $response = $fb->post('/me/videos', $data, $page_token); When I was try this, it is well work on my test page. [This video is uploaded that way.](https://www.facebook.com/Develop-test-page-106558804176943/?modal=admin_todo_tour). But I want to upload on the event page, not on my page.

Comment: The code I have posted is for video source, you can edit where post it with this rule : Publish videos to the following endpoints:

/{user-id}/videos
/{event-id}/videos
/{page-id}/videos
/{group-id}/videos          reference : [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/video-uploads/)

Comment: I also tried that. But I can't.
First of all, there are no videos in the event.
In the graph API explorer, I sent an "event_id / videos" request but no results.
If I post the video manually on the event page, we can see the post in the discussion tab.
There are videos on a group, page or user profile and "get ('object_id / videos', $ token)" command is executed but not on the event.
What do you think about it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Official reference for post video on event (Api Graph v5.0):

**Upload:**

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '{app-id}',
  'app_secret' => '{app-secret}',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
  ]);

$data = [
  'title' => 'My Foo Video',
  'description' => 'This video is full of foo and bar action.',
  'source' => $fb->videoToUpload('/path/to/foo_bar.mp4'),
];

try {
  $response = $fb->post('/me/videos', $data, 'user-access-token');
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

$graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
var_dump($graphNode);

echo 'Video ID: ' . $graphNode['id'];
```

**POST ON EVENT:**

```
/* PHP SDK v5.0.0 */
/* make the API call */
try {
  // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
  $response = $fb->get(
    '/{event-id}/videos',
    '{access-token}'
  );
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}
$graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
/* handle the result */
```

If you see the result JSON :

```
{
    "data": [],
    "paging": {}
}
```

All reference:
-[Start - Initialize an upload session](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/video-uploads/#start)
-[Transfer - Upload video chunks](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/video-uploads/#transfer)
-[Finish - Post the video](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/video-uploads/#finish)

**In the function:**

```
private function postFBVideo($authResponse, $fileObj, $formData)
    {
        FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('yourAppkey', 'yourAppSecret');
        $ajaxResponse = '';
        try {
            $session = new FacebookSession($authResponse->accessToken);
        } catch (FacebookRequestException $ex) {
            // When Facebook returns an error
            $ajaxResponse = 'FB Error ->' . json_encode($ex) ;
        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
            // When validation fails or other local issues
            $ajaxResponse = 'FB Validation Error - ' . json_encode($ex) ;
        }
        if ($session) {
            $response = (new FacebookRequest(
                $session, 'POST', '/.$idevent./videos', array(
                    'source' => new CURLFile('path', 'video/MOV'),
                    'message' => $formDataMessage,
                )
            ))->execute();
            $ajaxResponse = $response->getGraphObject();
        }
        return json_encode($ajaxResponse);
    }
```

Comment: Thank for your reply. But It doesn't work. Thre are no videos on the event page. So 'event-id/videos' is not recognized.

Comment: Edit answer, first upload then use that for post it to event.

Comment: $fb->post('/me/videos', $data, 'user-access-token'); This is well work. But I want to upload on event page, not the main page. $fb->get('event-id/videos', $token)----This result is null. And $fb->post('event-id/videos', $data, $token) It doesn't work. When I try this then got following error: "Graph returned an error:(#33) This object does not exist or does not support this action".  As a result, I have to upload the video to the event page and get it when needed.  Is this possible?

Comment: You have all permission for post video? reference : [HERE](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/video#publishing)

Comment: Of course, I have all permission related post the video.

Comment: If you succes upload video but doesnt have a preview try to add in data array `'image_url' => '<imageURL>'`

Comment: Moderator will create chat for post.

Comment: I don't understand where I should set 'image_url'. And I should upload the video on facebook and show it on the event page, not share links.

Comment: In data ARRAY, image_url set preview image try it

Comment: It is got following error. "error": {
    "message": "An unknown error occurred",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 1,
    "error_subcode": 1376033,
    "is_transient": false,
    "error_user_title": "Group Post Failure",
    "error_user_msg": "The message could not be posted to the group.",
    "fbtrace_id": "AYGoCPBBVROKsFEwimoHWPb"
  }. I think it doesn't recognize image_url.